# How embed only Apache Superset chart in React app

Tags: apache-superset

I want to embed Apache Superset chart to my React app.

I Using a Custom Security Manager by changing superset_config.py.

And in superset_config.py added:

```
TALISMAN_ENABLED = False
ENABLE_CORS = True
HTTP_HEADERS={"X-Frame-Options":"ALLOWALL"}
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react"

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <iframe
      title="Dashboard"
      src="http://localhost:8088/login?token=1234abcd456&next=/superset/dashboard/5?standalone=true"
      width="100%"
      height="800px"
      sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts">
      </iframe>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

When npm start, loading whole dashboard.

How to download only chart from dashboard?